# Converting a Subscription to a Subdomain in Plesk After Migration from cPanel

Tags: subdomain, cpanel, cloudflare, plesk

I recently faced a challenge after using the "Plesk Migrator" plugin to import several sites from a cPanel. The issue I'm encountering is that some of the subdomains have been incorrectly imported as separate subscriptions. This is causing a series of complications, especially with plugins like "Cloudflare DNS."

I'm seeking advice on how to convert a subscription back into a subdomain under a domain that's hosted in another subscription. This would rectify the current structure, aligning it with the original setup in cPanel.

Any guidance or solutions to this problem would be greatly appreciated.